# Not declared variable in default-constructed object in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor

The above code doesn't work. Indeed the default constructed object `f` in the constructor of `Foo` complains that the value `val` is not declared in the scope. I don't understand why it is not declared.

```
struct Foo2
{
  Foo2(int val)
  {}
};

struct Foo
{
  Foo(int val, Foo2 f = Foo2(val))
  {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo f(1);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use parameters in default parameters.

Comment: This question does not have any default constructors in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (8.3.6 Default arguments):

> 9 Default arguments are evaluated each time the function is called.
>   The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified.
>   Consequently, **parameters of a function shall not be used in a
>   default argument**, even if they are not evaluated. Parameters of a
>   function declared before a default argument are in scope and can hide
>   namespace and class member names.

In any C++ (not only C++ 2014) you can overload the constructor. For example

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int val )
  { Foo2 f(val); /*...*/ }
  Foo(int val, Foo2 f )
  {}
};
```

Or you can use a delegating constructor (if your compiler supports the new Standard)

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo(int val ) : Foo( val, Foo2( val ) )
  {}
  Foo(int val, Foo2 f )
  {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just how the language works; default arguments can't depend on other parameters, since the order of their initialisation is left unspecified.

In C++11 or later, you can work around this with an overload:

```
Foo(int val) : Foo(val, Foo2(val)) {}
```

Comment: Or you can use overloading.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos What's this then?

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: I am using overloading.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Foo2
{
    int x;
    Foo2(int val): x(val) {}
};

struct Foo
{
    int y;
    Foo2 f2;
    Foo(int val, Foo2 f): y(val), f2(f) {}
    Foo(int val): y(val), f2(val) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo f(1);
}
```

Comment: That assumes that `f2` is a member variable of `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates to solve this:

```
struct Foo2
{
  Foo2(int val)
  {}
};

template <int val>
struct Foo
{
  Foo(Foo2 f = Foo2(val))
  {}
};

int main()
{
  Foo<1> f = Foo<1>(); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but I want `val` to be a runtime variable

Comment: Ahh, you should have said that in the first place.